# terrafor from - create 3 server over 2 subnets using count

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

In terraform, I wish to create 3 servers while I'm having 2 subnets.
Creating 2 servers according to the below code will route both server and subnet ID according to the count - But what if I want 3 servers? I don't mind on which of the subnet the third server will be located.

```
resource "aws_instance" "consul_server" {
  count = 2
  ami           = "ami-00ddb0e5626798373"
  instance_type = t2.micro
  subnet_id = var.private_subnet_id[count.index]
  vpc_security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.consul_server.id]
  tags = {
    Name = "consul-server-${count.index + 1}-${var.project_name}"
    tag_enviroment= var.tag_enviroment
    project_name = var.project_name
    consul_server = "true"
    role = "consul-server"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally you would use [element](https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/element) to wrap-around indexing:

```
subnet_id = element(var.private_subnet_id, count.index)
```

Comment: Super. It is working.  Can you explain what is actually doing ?